# Display video on Sony Smartwatch version 1

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch, android-videoview

Long back I had bought the Sony smartwatch version 1. I am trying to display a layout containing the standard Android `VideoView` tag in XML.

Now, in smartwatch 1 the layout is changed using the `showBitmap` method. As seen from the `ControlExtension` sample, I have made my own layout containing only a VideoView that i want to display on the watch.

Basically, i want to know if the smartwatch version 1 can support the playing of a video. If not does the smartwatch 2 support it or is it not supported at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no APIs supported for video playback on either watch.  You can simulate video playback using a bitmap stream essentially by calling showBitmap() repeatedly but the bandwidth of video playback is limited by the Bluetooth connection, so playback will be choppy at best.

Comment: Ok @Marlin SONY. Thanks for the info. Does Sony plan on releasing an API in the future that may be has the sendVideo() kind of method ?

Comment: also how can I play a video on my Android phone when I click a button on the smartwatch? Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What about measuring heart rate, blood pressure etc. Does the Sony SDK provide health API's too?

Comment: There are currently no plans to support video playback on the watch.  Playing a video on the phone is the same as in standard Android.  The Smartwatch 1 and 2 do not have hardware sensors for health related services so those are also not supported.